# Why binding is not necessary in the some classes to call functions while not in others?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

Why Binding is'nt needed for the nep() to run in the image below,
[image]

but is needed for the hanndleSubmit() and formSubmit() to work, and throws error(onclick) if binding is removed!

[image]

I searched for this and got to know that binding are needed if we want to pass functions or variables as props without loosing their context, but in both example, props are not passed on to another component.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Comment: (oversimplified) `this` depends on how a function is called - by the way, in more modern javascript you can do `formSubmit = (event) => ..... etc` then you don't need to bind it

Comment: Thanks Phil, i did not know that, i was confused as to how to show people the error!

Comment: you didn't show any error though!

Comment: Jaromanda X, so this has some special property for forms? if it so, can you point me to some docs?

Comment: no, nothing to do with forms - it's to do with how `this` works in javascript - see the duplicate for a fully fleshed out answer

Comment: Also, the error runs off too fast to catch without event.preventDefault() , but it says "UnCaught"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use variables in the instance of a component like a state you must bind the instance on the method.

In the first example, you **call** the method, you did not bind it.

In the second example, you just bind the "formsubmit" method and it will fire when the button clicks.

it's different between `clicked={method}` and `clicked={method()}` the first one is binding and secound one is calling .

Comment: so, in the first example, i need not to bind it as its a method directly running, but in second ex. the method is to be called on a button click, thats why it needs binding? is this it?